# Use of unresolved Identifier within scope

Tags: swift

I am getting a problem with my swift code that I cant seem to figure out I have looked for answers but haven't found anyone with the same problem as me.

My Code is as follows:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController{

    var subjects = [String]()
    var defaultCell = "Cell"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func subjectForDisplay(atIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {

            _ = subjects[indexPath.row]
        }
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return subjects.count
            }

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(defaultCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = subjects[indexPath.row]
            return cell

    }
```

I am getting an error in the last function where it is giving me; Use of unresolved identifier 'defaultCell' and Use of unresolved identifier 'subjects'

Comment: Use Editor->Structure->Re-Indent (Ctrl-I) in Xcode, and you'll see the problem immediately ...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the closing curly brace right above `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath…`